# Summary part not displaying in preview mode in Filemaker

Tags: filemaker, summary

I have 2 tables in Filemaker Pro 11:

- `"Donor"` table holds several fields for the donor including:

  ```
  First Name
  Last Name
  Street Address
  City
  State
  ```
- Individual donations are tracked in the related `"Donation Transactions"` table and this has the following fields:

  ```
  Date
  Payment Type
  Amount
  Amount (Summary field: Running Total of the Amount field)
  ```

The two tables are joined by all the name and address fields. At this time, we do not have a unique number key column on the donor table hence have to use multiple fields to do this join.

I need to be able to generate various summary reports for the amount. For example, I may need to summarize by Month (based on `Date`'s value in the `"Donor Transactions"` table), by `City` (field on the parent `"Donors table"`). I followed a tutorial to generate the summary by `"Last Name"` as a starting report.

This is how the layout is defined:

```
[Header]       Last Name     Date       Payment Type         Amount          

[Sub-summary]  _LastName_                                    _Amount Running Total_

[Body]                       _Date_     _Payment Type_       _Amount_
```

.

Note: `[Sub-summary]` section is sorted on the `Last Name`, but it's not being displayed in preview mode. I can see it in the browse mode where one record is displayed at a time and the running total gets updated as I move from one record to another.

I would like to see the summaries in a table format with all the records sorted and displayed with the summary amount by name.

Any ideas on what I may have done wrong? I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Double check to make sure that everything is set up correctly:

#### The Basics:

In the **Donation Transactions** table:

- **amount** is set to number
- **amount summary** is set to **Summary = Total of Amount (running with restart), when sorted by Donor::Last Name**

The **relationship between Donor and Donation Transactions** should not matter as long as in the end you get a match between 1 donor and their multiple transactions (regardless of date, payment type or other attributes). You can play with the relationship later if you want to create specific filters.

#### The Report:

Here are the settings:

- report layout is based on the **Donor Transactions** table (if there are multiple occurrences of this, make sure you have the right one selected, the one with the correct relationship to the Donor table)
- **Sub-summary part** is set to: Sub-summary when sorted by **Donor::Last Name**
- **Body** contains Date, Payment Type and Amount
- **Sort** is done by **Donor::Last Name**

This should give you the report you are looking for.